# How to see progress sending multiple email with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, email

I've made an application for sending newsletter or mail marketing at my clients.
I select the email I want to send with a simple jquery script:

```
        $("#mktg_submit").on("click",function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#mktg_list").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "json/mktg.php",
                data: $("#mktg").serialize(),
                dataType    : 'json',
                encode      : true,
                timeout: 0, 
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if ((data)["success"]===false) {
                        $( "#mktg_list" ).append("<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+(data)["errors"]+"</div>");
                    } else {
                        $("#mktg_list").append("<div class='alert alert-success' id='mktg_mess'><strong>Well done!</strong></div>");
                        $.each((data)["email"], function( i, val ) {
                            $( "#mktg_list" ).append("<p>Email send: <b>"+val+"</b></p>");
                        });
                    }
                    $("#mktg_mess").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
                }
            });
        });
```

It works, but of course I can read the list of the emails  when the script ends.
How can I modify my script (or my json) to see the progress of the script?

example:

info@site1.com ok

me@site2.com sending

foo@site3.com scheduled

bar@site4.com scheduled
ecc

Comment: You could do using a websocket.